# Error: Unable to deserialize cloned data due to invalid or unsupported version

Tags: npm, parcel

I use parcel to deploy my web projects and on one occasion I got this error below while trying to deploy the page. I tried several solutions I saw online but none worked for me, I didn't even understand some.

```
  Error: Unable to deserialize cloned data due to invalid or unsupported version.
      at deserialize (node:v8:345:7)
      at deserialize (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\serializer.js:249:48)
      at RequestTracker.getRequestResult (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:635:54)
      at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:725:20)
      at async applyRuntimes (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\applyRuntimes.js:174:7)
      at async BundlerRunner.bundle (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\requests\BundleGraphRequest.js:287:25)
      at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:725:20)
      at async Object.run (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\requests\ParcelBuildRequest.js:62:7)
      at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\David Etuk\Documents\Front End Mentor Projects\E-Commerce Site\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:725:20)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What I did to resolve this was to delete the **.parcel-cache**, **dist**, and **node_modules** folders, then reinstall all lost packages with the command "**npm install or npm i**" and also build again with the command "**npm run start**" (or however you do it with parcel).

[my screen snip showing the error and the folders to be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMWC2.png)

Comment: Same for me - I had to remove `.parcel-cache` after using `nvm` to switch versions. Thanks @David.E !

Comment: For me I had to remove the .cache folder.

Comment: Just to add - at a low level, this is caused by changes to the V8 serialisation format (`import {serialize} from 'v8'` in Node) that sometimes happen between Node majors - caches written under older Node versions can't be read in newer versions, and vice-versa. Parcel could fix this by making the Node major part of the cache key.

Occasionally this also comes up with workers - child_process.fork and multiple Node versions installed (with nvm, etc) can't perform IPC for the same reason.

Answer (score 7):

You can likely get away with just deleting the `parcel-cache` folder and/or the `dist` folder. Doing both worked for me, next time I'll experiment with just deleting the `.parcel-cache` folder.

After that you can run your run/test command (i.e. `yarn start`) to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I was using the wrong Node version. So if you use nvm for managing Node versions, this should work: `nvm use 18.16.0` (or whatever version your project uses).

Answer (score 2):

Consider deleting the `node_modules, dist, parcel-cache` then you do `yarn install`

Answer (score 2):

if your project has a `.yarn/releases/` folder, try deleting the `.cjs` file in that folder and adding it back

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I resolved this issue by following similar steps to those mentioned in [Jason FB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76231419/5211833). However, I had to remove the entire *.yarn* folder and then moved it back. Simply removing the *.cjs* file did not work for me.